# How do I get valid dates, like using the ISDATE function without removing Null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Good day everyone!

I am using the T-SQL `ISDATE()` function with a date column as argument to filter out bad dates; the problem is the `ISDATE` function will return zero when it comes across a `NULL` value.

So with the example below; valid data in the table will be left out of the result set if there is a null for their dates. How can I remedy this so that I can get valid dates but also retrieve records with no dates? I need the records with no dates as well, I only need to remove those with bad dates, example, incomplete dates or dates missing characters.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ISDATE(MAYDATE) <> 0
```

Thanks my friends!

Comment: _"...with a date column as argument to filter out bad dates"_ seems contradictory. Use `datetime` datatype in the first place.

Comment: I am using a link table, and converting to date: However, I get a conversion error when bad dates are encountered. So I used ISDATE to get out bad dates:

Comment: I am getting the following error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. I think that's because I am trying to convert the date:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function, to replace the NULL value with a valid date value that is just used by the ISDATE function. Here are two examples:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ISDATE(ISNULL(MAYDATE, '1/1/1900')) <> 0
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ISDATE(ISNULL(MAYDATE, GETDATE())) <> 0
```

Or just check to see if the the value is NULL

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE (ISDATE(MAYDATE) <> 0) OR (MAYDATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: Why would you choose the inefficient 1st option over your 2nd.

Comment: @mouters I didn't consider the order that I presented the options or their efficiency when I wrote the answer. The ISNULL function is the first thing that came to mind when I read the question because it was logically very close (at least in my mind) to what he wanted. Then the simple comparison to NULL occurred right after. But with respect to efficiency, I just compared the Execution Plans in SSMS and they each had the same cost.

Comment: So there wouldn't be a scenario for choosing your 1st option over the 2nd. Its interesting to see that execution plans have the same cost.

Comment: I created a temp table and some sample data. The execution plan shows that all three queries have to do a table scan. Maybe a test on the real table schema and data (and possibly other query logic) it might prove there's a difference between the options. FWIW, now that I'm reviewing the answer again, I wouldn't choose the first option over the second.

Comment: @Adam Porad when you "alter" a column, it usually results in a table scan.  When you put the column `MAYDATE` within an `ISDATE()` function you will table scan.  The index is on the `MAYDATE` column value and not on the result of the `ISDATE()` function.  Imagine if you did this search on a phone book:  `WHERE LEN(Name)=6`  can you use the index (Name)? no the index is on the names not the length on the names, so to find all the names with a LEN()=6 you'd have to scan the entire phone book to get them all.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ISDATE(MAYDATE) <> 0 OR MAYDATE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for nulls first

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE MAYDATE is null or ISDATE(MAYDATE) <> 0
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I need the Records with no dates as well, I am only using the ISDATE() to remove wrong/bad dates, so if I check for nulls, wont I be losing those records without dates?

Comment: @Unaverage Guy, this is basically the same answer I already gave.  Rows will be returned that have a NULL date and rows will be returned that have a valid date as per ISDATE().  The query "says": return rows where the MAYDATE is NULL or MAYDATE is valid.

Comment: You'd be selecting records without dates ie maydate is null, or where isdate() returns true

Comment: I'm confused, why the down vote. The answer would work for the OP.

Comment: @mouters my answer received a down vote too. I'm not sure why either. It would be nice if down-voters would include a comment why, so that we could learn to improve our answers.

Comment: Indeed, I actually don't care for the vote but I'm interested to know why this wouldn't work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE (MAYDATE IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE(MAYDATE) <> 0)
     OR (MYDATE IS NULL)
```